# Nagios script to check Nagios

Tags: monitoring, nagios

I am currently running multiple (6) Nagios instances across multiple projects. My concept is to run one Nagios instance per project, each responsible for the machines below them and with project specific tasks.

Yes, I could roll all of these into one Nagios instance but this is not the question.

I have checked Google and Nagios Exchange looking for a plugin and if there is nothing out there I will build one myself. I want to know if anyone has any experience with this.

Question:
Is there a Nagios plugin which will check the overall status of another remote Nagios instance, either through NRPE and a local script, or over authenticated HTTP(s) to the cgi-bin, simply reporting on how many are OK / Warning / Critical / Unknown, etc in each checked instance. HTTP(s) would be preferred.

If not, can someone point me in the direction of how to query and understand the responses of a single Nagios instance. If there is not any existing plugins I will start looking at Nagstamon for guidance on how to achieve this.

Answer (score 2):

I don't understand if you want to check if every Nagios is running OK, in such case you can use check_nagios plugin.

If you mean you want to see every Nagios check in one place you can use MNTOS, it will show you every Nagios tactical overview in one place. If that's not enough you can check [this link](http://www.openlogic.com/wazi/bid/188134/How-to-Build-a-Distributed-Monitoring-Solution-with-Nagios) to show you other Nagios checks in your "master" Nagios

Answer (score 0):

I am in the process of developing web services  RESTful API for Nagios.

If is still work in progress, but current version (0.2) can retrieve all hosts status, and all service status over HTTP, and additionally configuration of objects.

It is also possible to submit passive check results for hosts and service status.

Please check http://dmytro.github.com/nagira, it is also published on Nagios Exchange in API section.

Is this something you are looking for?

Answer (score 0):

You could use the mentioned check_nagios invoked via nrpe/check_by_ssh/snmp but you also should make sure that the host itsself is being monitored - e.g. filesystems, load, etc.

You might have a look at the Icinga Wiki, where I'm keeping such a list on what to monitor on a monitoring host: https://wiki.icinga.org/display/howtos/Monitoring+the+Icinga+Host

A slightly different approach will be parsing the status.dat manually fetching last_check. An example (also usable for Nagios, not only Icinga) targetting snmp can be found here: https://wiki.icinga.org/display/howtos/check_snmp_icinga